How many relations of n - elements are symmetric, transitive but not reflexive?
Consider that there are n elements in a given set. We have to count the number of relations which are symmetric, transitive but not reflexive. By not reflexive I mean it should be irreflexive or non - reflexive.

Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match many users' quality standards, so it may attract downvotes, or be closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. This will help you recognize and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

If it is symmetric and transitive but not reflexive, then it's symmetric and transitive but not an equivalence relation. Hence this is a duplicate of this question

This question is similar to: symmetric,transitive but not equivalence relation.. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
